# Show and hide <div>'s with data from a JSON Stream?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stream

So here is my dilemma, I am sending a stream of JSON data from a php function and I catch that data with a javascript library called Oboe.js (http://oboejs.com/).

I succeed to show the stream of objects retrieved form the API, and append them to a div with jQuery.

My problem is that, due to the quantity of objects I receive (more than 20000) the browser slows down and sometimes crashes. What I would like to achieve is to show some of the data and keep loading the objects without showing them, and when pressing a button, like a pagination button (or it could also be an infinite scroll), hide the elements already shown and show some other few ones, etc.

The code it's something like this:

```
oboe('jsonStream.json')
   .node('!*', function( item ){
      $('#products').append('<div class="new_product">item.name</div>');
   });
```

Comment: If you know how many you want to show each time (20, for example), you could declare the json object, i = 0 and j = 20 as globals.  Load the first 20 with a `for` loop, then, 'on click' of a pagination button, add 20 to j and run the json object through the loop again.  not that pretty, but should prevent the browser crash

Comment: There are numerous pagination plugins available for doing this. Keep that many elements out of the DOM and render on demand by user using filters and/or paginating